# Should I run 'git gc' for every working directory?

Tags: git, garbage-collection

I sometimes run [`git gc`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html) to clean up files and improve performance, usually with a cronjob. However, I also use [`git-new-workdir`](http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/git-new-workdir/) to create a new working directory with its own index.

Does it make sense to run `git gc` on each of those working directories? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because the underlying repository is shared by all those separate working directories, and `git gc` operates on the underlying repository.

There's an additional (minor but real) danger here.  When you run `git gc`, it cleans and compresses repository objects, discarding those that are unreferenced.  Some references may, in some cases, be only in the index, or only in `HEAD` (in "detached HEAD" mode).  But note that in the description of [`git-new-workdir`](http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/git-new-workdir/), it says, in part:

> it simply sets up a new working directory (with its own index) for you.

References hidden in some other index—i.e., any index that is not the one seen with the work-dir—are invisible to `git gc`, making them eligible for removal.

Most of this time this is not going to be a problem because `git gc` runs `git prune` with the default expiration time (i.e., 2 weeks) for unreferenced objects.  An index-only reference occurs when you `git add` a file but don't `git commit` the result, so these apparently-stale references would only go away if you leave `git add`ed files uncommitted for at least two weeks ... and you can always fix the problem by `git add`-ing the file(s) again as needed.

A more insidious version occurs with the use of a detached HEAD to create an anonymous branch.  The page you linked does not mention it, but the new-workdir script does not (and cannot) maintain such detached HEADs across separate "new work dirs" (each of these new directories has its own `.git` directory with its own separate `HEAD` reference).  A two or more week old chain of detached commits could be discarded from the underlying repository if the `git gc` is run in some other work directory.

This is not a problem for "real" branches and tags as the script shares "deeper" references (including branches and tags).  That is, updating branch X in one work-dir updates branch X in all other work-dirs, so that there's no way to lose a reference.

In short (too late? :-) ) you're reasonably safe if you don't keep detached HEADs out for more than a week.

Answer (score 2):

No, it makes no sense. Run it once.

`git gc` does not modify anything in the working directory. It *only* modifies things in the `.git` directory. The entire point of `git-new-workdir` is to share a single `.git` between multiple working directories, so running `git gc` from two different working directories is identical to running it twice from the same directory; that is to say, it is pointless.